How to pack const reference in template parameter to std::array?
In C++20 or later, how to pack the const references of constexpr objects in template parameter list to an array? Something like following code, noticing the ... is not in foo() but only in template <>.
using Key = std::string_view;
template <const Key & ... KS>
consteval auto foo()
{
    return std::to_array<Key>(KS ...); // compile error
}

constexpr inline Key k1 = "abc";
constexpr inline Key k2 = "xyz";

auto a = foo<k1, k2>();

Is there something like std::forward_as_tuple I can use? Perhaps something called forward_as_array.

Thanks everyone, I got this done. See my answer below.

return std::array{KS...}; ? You can't have arrays of references though. return std::forward_as_tuple(KS...); would work too.

What's the point of passing via template arguments instead of function arguments? An array can't hold references directly. You would need to return a std::array<std::reference_wrapper<const Key>> or std::tuple<const Key&, ...> or std::array<const Key*> instead.

@user17732522 Yeah, that's right. Actually I want to put a copy into the constexpr array.

@SonullxLiu So, return std::array{KS...}; then?  auto a = foo<k1, k2>; doesn't work though. You must actually call the function.

Just as a side note, it doesn't really make a whole lot of sense to put references to std::string_view that are constructed from string literals into a container...

What's the error message? Others with the same question should have the option to use that to find your post.

return std::array{KS ...} works fine for me.

Actually it works this way:
using Key = std::string_view;

template <const Key & ... KS>
consteval auto foo()
{
    return std::array<Key, sizeof ... (KS)>{KS ...};
}

constexpr inline Key k1 = "abc";
constexpr inline Key k2 = "xyz";

static void bar()
{
    auto a = foo<k1, k2>();
}

No compile error.
